# EditText.getText().toString() comparison to other string fails

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, tostring

The Toast keeps saying access denied, even if i fill in the right pin.

I need to lock users into an kiosk-mode app, and only with the right pin they will have access to the settings and the exit option.

```
            public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FullscreenActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("PIN:");
            //alert.setMessage("Message");

            final EditText pinEntry = new EditText(FullscreenActivity.this);
            alert.setView(pinEntry);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String pin = pinEntry.getText().toString().trim();
                    String secret = "0000";
                    if (pin == secret){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Access Approved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Access Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: instead of 'pin == secret' try pin.equals(secret)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`==` tests for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are compared with `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`, not with the double equals `==` like you are using.  change your if statement from `if(pin == secret)` to `if(pin.equals(secret))` if they are cap-sensitive, or `if(pin.equalsIgnoreCase(secret))` if case does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String pin = pinEntry.getText().toString().trim();
                    String secret = "0000";
                    if (pin.equalsIgnoreCase( secret)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Access Approved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Access Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```